# Recursive function in Java - thread safe collection

Tags: java, multithreading, copyonwritearraylist

Lets suppose I have a xml documents in which i can find links to the other documents of the same type which can also have a links to another one documents. At starting point I have list of documents to read and analise. I have written following algorithm to read and analise those documents:

```
    private static List<String> documentNames = new ArrayList<String>();

    main(...) {
       //add names to documentNames arrayList above.
       for(String documentName : documentNames) {
           readDocument(documentName);
        }
    }
```

Function readDocument looks following:

```
       private static CopyOnWriteArrayList<String> visitURL(String documentName) {
       CopyOnWriteArrayList<String> visitedDocs = new CopyOnWriteArrayList<String>(); //visited Ref urls
         if (!visitedDocs .contains(documentName)) {
            analyseAndWriteOnDisk(documentName)    //it saves analised document on disk
            CopyOnWriteArrayList<String> tmp = visitURL(documentName);
            visitedDocs.addAll(tmp);
         } else {
            System.out.println(documentName " - I have seen it !");
         }
         return visitedDocs;
       }
```

It works, but after execution of the programm I can find duplicate files (files with the same content). I shouldnt have them - I prevent it by if-condition in function visitURL. My question is: what doesn't work here ? I suppose that something is wrong with with manipulation with array visitedDocs. How can I get on every recursion call actuall version of array with already visited files ?

Being as most precise as I can, I have a recursion function which operates on some collection X:

```
   recursion(CollectionType X) {
      someoperations(X)
      recursion(X)
   }
```

and `X` must be always actual.

Comment: I'm going to note that the listed code doesn't ever call `visitURL` the first time... it calls `readDocument` and you haven't given us the code for that.

Comment: Where do you extract the links from a document?

Answer (score 0):

Each time you call `visitURL`, you're creating a new instance of `visitedDocs`. So, it's empty every time at the beginning of the call, and at the end contains only the current iteration of `tmp`.

According to JavaDocs, you need to call the new one like this:

`CopyOnWriteArrayList<String> visitedDocs = new CopyOnWriteArrayList<String>(documentNames) //here you need to add the parameter of the ArrayList you want to copy, otherwise you're instantiating a blank ArrayList.`

Then, you'll need to set your `documentNames` equal to the returned `visitedDocs`.

Comment: Can I achieve something simillar by creatic static ArrayList somewhere in code ? In result I just want have on every level in recursion a object with already visited documents.

Comment: Yes, you should be able to. You need to have the static CopyOnWriteArrayList declared somewhere in the Class that's most persistent, but that `visitURL` has access to. Such as `private static CopyOnWriteArrayList<String> visitedList = new CopyOnWriteArrayList<String>();`. Then your code inside `visitURL()` would be: `CopyOnWriteArrayList<String> visitedDocs = new CopyOnWriteArrayList<String>(visitedList);`
Unfortunately, without seeing the whole class I can't tell you where the static var should be.

Answer (score 0):

You should not use a recursive algorithm for that. It's easier to use a queue that holds all documents to analyze, and a set that holds all documents that are already analyzed. As long as the queue is not empty, you pull a document from it, analyze it and add extracted links to the queue if they are not already visited.

```
private Collection<String> visit(Collection<String> intialDocs) {
    Queue<String> documents = new LinkedBlockingQueue(initialDocs);
    Set<String> visited = new HashSet<>();
    while (!documents.isEmpty()) {
        String doc = documents.poll();
        visited.add(doc);

        Collection<String> links = analyzeDocument(doc);
        for(String link : links) {
            if (!visited.contains(link) documents.add(link);
        }
    }
    return visited;
}

private Collection<String> analyzeDocument(String document) {
    // TODO: analyze document and return a list of all links in that document
}
```

Usage:

```
Set<String> allVisitedDocuments = visit(documentNames);
```

Advantage of this iterative approach over recursive solution:

- It is easier to see how it works.
- It is easier to argue that it will terminate.
- It is easier to debug.
- It can easily be parallelized if required.
- Order of document processing can easily be influenced by just changing the type of collection used for queueing the documents. (Now it performs a breadth-first search, if you use a LIFO like `Stack` instead, you get depth-first, and some priority-queue might let you decide based on document type or so).
- If you have long series of linked documents, recursion may become very deep and a stack overflow may happen.

Note: If you don't use multiple threads, you should **not** use `CopyOnWriteArrayList` as it makes a full copy of its internal content on *every* write access!

Comment: I can try it tomorrow and check how it works. Thank you for this idea. Can you explain why I shouldn't use recursive algorithm for it ? And how I should use this function ? What to do with returned visited queue ?

Comment: I've modified my answer to address your first question. Concerning return value: It is not required to return the visited documents, but as I don't know if you need this collection somewhere outside the algorithm, I decided to do so. Feel free to skip.

Comment: Now I see that I can't use this. I need to know how deep in the document tree I am in order to prepare formatted log file

Comment: Hm, that would have been a very important information! How do you want to treat documents, that are linked in multiple documents? Just log them when visited for the first time, or every time?

Comment: Thank you for help. I re-think my own code and I found a bug there. Now it works.... just two instructions should be inside if-statement :)

Comment: You're welcome! Don't forget to get rid of that `CopyOnWriteArrayList`!